# How can I filter empty values from an object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am trying to filter out empty entries in an object.

For example an object like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [maten0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [XXS] => 
            [XS] => 
            [S] => 10
            [M] => 10
            [L] => 
            [XL] => 
            [XXL] => 
        )

)
```

The desired output would be:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [maten0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [S] => 10
            [M] => 10
        )

)
```

I create the object with json. Like so:

```
$kuubobject = json_decode($artikel['aantalkuub']);
```

I found out how to do this with arrays but the following does not work for objects:

```
$filteredobject = array_filter($kuubobject, 'strleng');
```

This gives me the error:

```
array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
```

How can I do this with objects?

I've tried the following after the marked duplicate question:

```
$object = (object) array_filter((array) $kuubobject);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($object);
echo '</pre>';
```

But I get the same output as above.

Comment: Why not `$kuubobject = json_decode($artikel['aantalkuub'], true);` and then you be able to use `array_filter`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter`

```
$filteredobject  = array_filter((array)$object->maten0);
```

Comment: Thanks but `maten0` can be different anytime so adding it like this will not work for all my objects. Another page can have `maten1` for example.

Comment: if it's different then you can `foreach` and use `$object->{$key}`